# Is it possible to set the DataContext through a trigger in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set the Data Context of a parent StackPanel depending on a boolean value.

I have a boolean value named `IsProductMode`.

```
private bool isProductMode;
public bool IsProductMode
{
    get { return isProductMode; }
    set { isProductMode = value; RaisePropertyChange("IsProductMode"); }
}
```

I wanted said boolean to toggle the DataContext of a StackPanel and either bind them to my `EditFormSelectedProduct` or `EditFormSelectedService` that both has the property `Name` being bound to the Stack Panel's child TextBox's text.

```
<StackPanel>
   <Label Content="Name" />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
   <StackPanel.Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
           <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding EditFormSelectedProduct}"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsProductMode}" Value="False">
                   <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding EditFormSelectedService}"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </StackPanel.Style>
</StackPanel>
```

What I've Tried:

I've tried removing the trigger and tried setting the Data Context first to `EditFormSelectedProduct` and then `EditFormSelectedService`. The results were that the TextBox displayed the correct `Name` values depending on its Data Context. So at the very least, I proved that the sources were indeed populated and that their bindings work.

For now I've temporarily settled on having two Stack Panels, each with their own appropriate Data Context and set their visibilities depending on `IsProductMode`.

What I expected:

I expected it to set the appropriate Data Context depending on the boolean value but it keeps on being set to `EditFormSelectedProduct` regardless of the boolean's value.

Comment: `Binding="{Binding IsProductMode}"` resolves the property against the current DataContext. So is there a IsProductMode property in EditFormSelectedProduct?

Comment: Setting an element's DataContext by a Style looks odd. What you should actually do is to define two DataTemplates for both modes and show your data in a ContentControl. Either let the DataTemplate be automatically selected by their DataType (in case both modes have different type), or write a DataTemplateSelector that returns the appropriate DataTemplate depending on the IsProductMode property. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally overlooked that I set a default Data Context and then proceeded to look inside it with the `IsProductMode` when I thought I was still in the base View Model. So I set the Trigger instead to                                         `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsProductMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=1}}" Value="False">` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Also thanks for the info on Data Templating, I'm always very open to improving my code and I'm very grateful that your reply not only helped me with my current problem, but also opened the doors for me to learn something else as well.